# WPF.RoutedEvents,Commands,Dependecy Properties tutorial?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am looking for a good tutorial preferably video that teaches SLOWLY and throughtly what are:
RoutedEvents,Commands,Dependecy Properties

and how to use them in order to create large scale WPF project.

I have tried to watch a few tutrials and read the MSDNand got very confused.

Comment: Sorry, these kinds of questions aren't welcome here.  However, if you have any *specific* questions about each, please do feel free to ask them.  It usually helps to create a small prototype to learn about each.  Also, reading through some of the related tags here will show you the common issues with each.

Answer (score 2):

I really do not find MSDN to be confusing, do you mean the respective overviews?

- [Routed Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx)
- [Commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308.aspx)
- [Dependency Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx)

(*I could imagine them to be confusing if you only skim them though*)

Comment: +1 I don't know, it uses some pretty big words ;-)

Comment: @Colin E: You gotta start somewhere, preferably not in pre-school.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to MSDN you may want to check out [Josh Smith's blog](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/). He uses a conversational voice that I find enjoyable to read and easy to understand.

Here are some links to the topic you mention:

[Dependency Properties](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/05/16/demystifying-dependency-properties/)

[Routed Events](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/06/22/overview-of-routed-events-in-wpf/)

[Command](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2008/03/18/understanding-routed-commands/)

I hope this helps!